# @vue/cli | vue create <namehere> won't work with node v12.18.3

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

I'm wondering if @vue/cli doesn't work with node v12.18.3
I checked the vue/cli files and found it's been using npm v.6.4.0,
yet when I check my version of npm, it's v6.14.8

Explained a bit more:

`vue create <projectname>`
Instantly I get this:

> npm err! cb.apply is not a function

when I check the logs, it says:

> 19 verbose node v12.18.3 
> 20 verbose npm  v6.4.0 
> 21 error cb.apply is not a function

So I'm just assuming the only way for @vue/cli to work for me is if I downgrade node.js to a version that works with npm v6.4.0 or is there some kind of work around to get vue to work with my current node version??

version of @vue/cli -> v4.5.4

> **FIXED: just had to completely reinstall nodejs and npm, reboot, etc**

Comment: Vue CLI 4.5.4 works with Node 12.8.3, as I just confirmed on macOS Catalina.

Comment: Must have to do with npm then on my pc then; npm works fine until i use vue or react "create" cmds, they wont work & then the logs say my npm is an older version.